# Raspberry pi very slow boot

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os, docker, reboot

I have a very slow reboot of raspberry pi 4 (8gb ram). It wasnt always like this,
but the last days i realized it's extremely slow.
I use it for Home assistant (with Docker), pihole and plex, and i have a usb mounted for extra space. Is the SD card getting old and i should go for an SSD?
Here are my results:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @44.592s
└─multi-user.target @44.591s
  └─docker.service @15.619s +27.622s
    └─network-online.target @15.580s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @8.746s +6.831s
        └─NetworkManager.service @6.280s +2.460s
          └─dbus.service @6.239s
            └─basic.target @6.107s
              └─sockets.target @6.107s
                └─docker.socket @6.070s +36ms
                  └─sysinit.target @6.058s
                    └─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount @15.478s +26ms
                      └─systemd-modules-load.service @1.137s +133ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @1.125s
                          └─system.slice @1.096s
                            └─-.slice @1.096s
```

Comment: Looking at the critical-chain output, that's 44s to graphical target -- but **the last ~27 seconds were taken by docker**, implying that if you weren't using it, you'd boot in < 20s which does not seem that bad to me (but then, I do not boot GUI pis much).   So if you are looking for a culprit, look into that.  Keep in mind that "mebbe I need a new SD card" is sometimes treated as a panacea by pi users because of some unfortunate memes that have proliferated in the community -- easy to do, but I would guess mostly a waste of time, etc.

Comment: i use docker for the Home Assistant, which is the main reason for the raspberry pi running. From what you are saying 44s is still normal?

Comment: I have no opinion on the normalcy of 44s, although I did say *20s* does not seem too bad.  My point was most of your boot time seems to be taken up by docker.

Comment: i believe that my sd is kind of corrupted. About SSD i see everywhere even if its not extremely faster, is much more stable. i'm thinking to buy another SD and test. it's not only the boot time, it is very very slow for every task..